# Geomesa not connecting

Tags: geotools, accumulo, geomesa

I have a full accumulo (2.1.1)/geomesa (2.13) install and a VDI installed on the same server.  It has the following configured (but only using the first zookeeper)

```
zookeeper1 192.168.2.31
zookeeper2 192.168.2.32
zookeeper3 192.168.2.33
namenode   192.168.2.34
datanode1  192.168.2.35
datanode2  192.168.3.36
acc-master 192.168.2.37
acc-tserver 192.168.2.38
```

My connection is trying to be established with this:

```
Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();
parameters.put("accumulo.instance.name", "myInstance");
parameters.put("accumulo.zookeepers", "127.0.0.1:9997");
parameters.put("accumulo.user", "keith");
parameters.put("accumulo.password", "accumulo2.1");
parameters.put("accumulo.catalog", "myNamespace.keithCatalog");
try {
    store = DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(parameters);
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

When I try to connect, it never returns.  No errors, nothing.  Just jams.

The schema was created with this:

```
/opt/geomesa-accumulo_2.12-4.0.1/bin/geomesa-accumulo create-schema -c myNamespace.keithCatalog -s source:String,sensor:String,type:String,date:Date -f testSchema
```

I can see the test schema from the acc-master box by this:

```
sudo /opt/geomesa-accumulo_2.12-4.0.1/bin/geomesa-accumulo describe-schema -c myNamespace.keithCalog -f testSchema
INFO  Describing attributes of feature 'testSchema'
source | String
sensor | String
type   | String
date   | Date


User data:
  geomesa.index.dtg    | date
  geomesa.indices      | id:4:3:
  geomesa.stats.enable | true
```

If I leave out the catalog it naturally errors.  If I put a wrong catalog in there it still never returns.

In my code if I get the available datastores via DataStoreFinder.getAllDataStores(), I get this so it looks like it is there:

```
org.locationtech.geomesa.accumulo.data.AccumuloDataStoreFactory@18e36d14
 Info:
  accumulo.instance.name=java.lang.String Accumulo Instance Name
  accumulo.zookeepers=java.lang.String Zookeepers
  accumulo.catalog=java.lang.String REQUIRED Accumulo catalog table name, including Accumulo namespace (if any) separated with a period
  accumulo.user=java.lang.String Accumulo user
  accumulo.password=java.lang.String Accumulo password
  accumulo.keytab.path=java.lang.String Path to keytab file
  geomesa.query.threads=java.lang.Integer The number of threads to use per query
  accumulo.query.record-threads=java.lang.Integer The number of threads to use for record retrieval
  accumulo.write.threads=java.lang.Integer The number of threads to use for writing records
  geomesa.query.timeout=java.lang.String The max time a query will be allowed to run before being killed, e.g. '60 seconds'
  accumulo.zookeepers.timeout=java.lang.String The timeout used for connections to Zookeeper
  accumulo.remote.arrow.enable=java.lang.Boolean Process Arrow encoding in Accumulo tablets servers as a distributed call
  accumulo.remote.bin.enable=java.lang.Boolean Process binary encoding in Accumulo tablets servers as a distributed call
  accumulo.remote.density.enable=java.lang.Boolean Process heatmap encoding in Accumulo tablets servers as a distributed call
  accumulo.remote.stats.enable=java.lang.Boolean Process statistical calculations in Accumulo tablets servers as a distributed call
  geomesa.stats.enable=java.lang.Boolean Generate and persist data statistics for new feature types
  geomesa.query.audit=java.lang.Boolean Audit queries being run
  geomesa.query.loose-bounding-box=java.lang.Boolean Use loose bounding boxes - queries will be faster but may return extraneous results
  geomesa.partition.scan.parallel=java.lang.Boolean Run scans in parallel for partitioned stores
  geomesa.security.auths=java.lang.String Super-set of authorizations that will be used for queries. The actual authorizations might differ, depending on the authorizations provider, but will be outside this set. Comma-delimited.
  geomesa.security.auths.force-empty=java.lang.Boolean Default to using no authorizations during queries, instead of using the connection user's authorizations
  namespace=java.lang.String Namespace
  password=java.lang.String
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Expected to get data store back

Answer (score 0):

I believe your data store parameters are wrong, and it is trying to connect to zookeeper and hanging. When using the `geomesa-accumulo` command line tools, GeoMesa is likely picking up the `accumulo-client.properties` file from your Accumulo install, which is letting it connect. You can simply [place that file on the classpath of your application](https://www.geomesa.org/documentation/stable/user/accumulo/usage.html#creating-a-data-store), instead of passing in the instance/zookeepers/user/password. Otherwise, you'll need to fix the data store parameters. In particular, the `127.0.0.1:9997` looks incorrect, as you said that zookeeper is on `192.168.2.31`,`32`, and `33`, and zookeeper usually listens on port `2181` (not `9997`, which is the port Accumulo uses to communicate with tablet servers).

Comment: Thank you so much for answering.  I actually do have the zookeeper set to

parameters.put("accumulo.zookeepers", "192.168.2.31");

Just copied the info off of my local machine from when I was trying to connect from here instead of the VDI.  Will try the properties file.

Answer (score 0):

So this has been resolved.  It was a configuration issue with the GeoMesa install.  Thank you.

-Keith

Comment: Answers (and questions) should be written such that future users can learn from them, too. Please either [edit] this answer to provide details about what was wrong, or consider deleting your question entirely (I think you'll have to delete this answer first).